# how to enforce uniqueness of non-unique key in Oracle table for each task

Tags: oracle

title can be a little confusing - I will deep down into details here ...

Imagine simplified log table:

```
run_id  |  step_id  |  result |
--------------------------------
   1    |     1     |  done   |
   1    |     2     |  done   |
   1    |     3     |  done   |
   1    |     4     |  done   |
   2    |     1     | failed  |
   3    |     1     |  done   |
   3    |     2     |  done   |
```

But when I run two jobs (with run_id 1 and 2) in the same time, it happens they share the run_id which is not correct !!

I want for each job to have separate id .. obviously :)

How to enforce it in Oracle (PL/SQL - mostly packages) for jobs starting at the very same time (i.e. 6am) ...

do you have any idea? How do u solve this kind of situation? What if I create unique index over (run_id, step_id) ?? Will the "second" job fail? Or will it automatically increment the value?

```
SELECT nvl(max(run_id), 0)+1 INTO v_run_id
FROM my_schema.log_table;
```

This is the code, getting the new value ... but it doesn't work, because of ... as above

thx

EDIT:
as a workaround I thought about using strings and dates ... to use start_date and constant string (run_name instead of run_id) ...  so the table can look like

```
run_name  |      run_date         | step_id  |  result |
--------------------------------------------------------
 my_job#1 |  1/1/2016 7:00:00 AM  |   1      |  done   |
 my_job#1 |  1/1/2016 7:00:00 AM  |   2      |  done   |
 my_job#1 |  1/1/2016 7:00:00 AM  |   3      |  done   |
 my_job#1 |  1/1/2016 7:00:00 AM  |   4      |  done   |
 my_job#2 |  1/1/2016 7:00:00 AM  |   1      | failed  |
 my_job#1 |  1/2/2016 7:00:00 AM  |   1      |  done   |
 my_job#1 |  1/2/2016 7:00:00 AM  |   2      |  done   |
```

This could work .. I am just curious how to do it with IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are obtaining a run_id like this currently:

```
SELECT nvl(max(run_id), 0)+1 INTO v_run_id
FROM my_schema.log_table;
```

I assume your code then uses the `run_id` when inserting for each step. You should create a sequence like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE run_id_seq;
```

And then replace your above query with:

```
SELECT run_id_seq.nextval FROM dual;
```

If you already have existing data in your table, you might need to `START WITH` a value when creating your sequence to make sure it does not clash.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to handle this is using sequences.  In Oracle 12c, you can use the `generated always` construct to assign a sequential value to a column automatically (like `identity`, `serial`, and `auto_increment` in other databases).

In older versions, you maintain it using a trigger.  After defining a column in the table and a sequence, the trigger code looks like:

```
create trigger t_trigger
before insert on t
for each row
begin
    select seq.nextval into new.id
    from dual;
end;
```

With such a construct, the values can never be the same.

Comment: but this means I will get different run_id per each insert correct? I won't be able to identify the same "run" by run_id

Comment: @Mr.P yes you would.  So in your case you need to get the value from the sequence directly rather than using a trigger for each row inserted.